# Where am I going wrong with Sentinel or break in this Python code

Tags: python

Okay this program is almost done but it keeps running. Need to figure out where the sentinel or break needs to go. This is what I have so far in Python. The program is suppose to read all the Pres on the list and print them. Then there is a slice removing the first two and last two.Then it prints the list size is 6 and then proceeds to give me the 6 Pres in alpha reverse order. I have everything working other than its repeating the end indefinitely. There has to be a while loop to display the elements in the list returned by playlist.

```
Pres = ['Kennedy','Johnson','Nixon','Ford','Carter','Reagan',\
        'Bush','Clinton','Bush','Obama'] 
Pres2 = Pres[2:8]

def main():

    for names in Pres:

        print(names)


    PR3=playlist(Pres2)
    while playlist !='6':
            for PR3 in Pres2:
                    print(PR3)


def playlist(PR):

    size = len(PR)
    print('list size is now', size)

    PR.sort()
    PR.reverse()
    return PR

main()
```

Now this is what I **should** get when I run it.

```
Kennedy
Johnson
Nixon
Ford
Carter
Reagan
Bush
Clinton
Bush
Obama
list size is now 6
Reagan
Nixon
Ford
Clinton
Carter
Bush
```

But instead after List size is now 6, the last 6 Presidents just keeps repeating. And it needs to read vertically on its own line.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you have some problems understanding even the basics of programming. I strongly encourage you to read again the courses that you had already read.

Nevertheless, here are some explanations:

- `playlist` is actually a function. This `while playlist !='6'` loop is just verifying that this function object is not a string. It is always different, so. If you want to compare the result of the function, you have to call it: `playlist(PR)`, this will execute the function and return a list that you can store in a variable.
- Your `playlist` function is returning a `list` object. Why do you try to compare it with `'6'`?
  Moreover, `'6'` is not the length of your list. It is a string. `6` is the length of your list as it is an int.
- Why do you use a `while` loop since you only want the six Presidents to being displayed once? This does not make sense. A loop is for actions which need to be repeated an unknown number of times.
- As `Pres2` is sliced from `Pres` at the beginning, its length is 6. Its length has never been higher, and even assuming that your loop had been properly drafted, the code inside would never have been executed.
- When you use `for` loop to iterate trough a list, the variable written after `for` is used as an alias which represents the current object iterated from your list. `for PR3 in Pres2:` is weird as you already defined a variable called `PR3`. If you want to display president inside the list, then you just as to use `for name in PR3` as you did before.

Let me show you an enhanced version of the function, hoping that you manage to understand better how it works:

```
def main():

    # Print the 10 Presidents
    for name in Pres:
        print(name)

    # Print the size of the list which already contains 6 Presidents
    # Then, sort the list, reverse it and return it
    # The new list is store into PR3
    PR3 = playlist(Pres2)

    # Print the 6 reverse sorted Presidents
    for name in PR3:
        print(name)
```

Did you get it? You have absolutely no need to use a loop.

Comment: This is why I am confused. I can get it without a loop but the assignment is this.

Comment: @BillMatias What is exactly your assignment?

Comment: `while playlist !='6'` makes no sense, it should be `while playlist(PR) !='6'`. Or probably `while len(playlist(PR)) !='6'` But as you said playlist() never changes the list length anyway.

Answer (score 0):

1. Write a single program named mylist.py as follows. Follow instructions carefully to avoid point deductions.

In the main function:

create a list that holds the surnames of recent USA presidents, starting with Kennedy and ending with Obama, in chronological order.
use a for loop to iterate over the entire list, printing each president's name on its own line.
make a slice by removing the first two presidents and the last two presidents from the list.
pass the new slice as an argument to a custom function named playlist.
use a while loop to display the elements in the list returned by playlist.
In the playlist function:

print the size of the sliced list. Use a list function.
sort the sliced list in reverse alphabetical order.
return this list to main.
Sample Output
Original list in main:
Kennedy
Johnson
Nixon
Ford
Carter
Reagan
Bush
Clinton
Bush
Obama
Not in main: list size is now 6
Back in main, list in reverse alpha order
Reagan
Nixon
Ford
Clinton
Carter
Bush

It calls for a while loop in the main function